# Why is the default catch-all not mandatory in a Haskell case statement?

Tags: haskell

Haskell has a reputation for being a *safe* language. One that generally speaking pushes more of the possible programming errors to compile-time errors, and less and run-time.

One example of this is the `if` expression. The `else` in the if is always mandatory. You need to cover off both possibilities. This is great because you have thought and covered off all possibilities of what will happen at runtime.

Now Haskell has a `case` expression. (This bears some similarity to `switch` statements in other OO and imperative languages - but Haskell adds a lot of richness in the type system).

```
describeList :: [a]
describeList xs = "The list is " ++ case cs of [] -> "empty."
                                               [x] -> "a singleton list."
                                               xs -> "a longer list."
```

But with the `case` expression, the default 'catch-all' is not mandatory.

To me this sounds like it would lead to runtime errors.

My question is: **Why is the default catch-all not mandatory in a Haskell `case` statement?**

Comment: You could write `_ -> error "should never happen"`, but that's the default behaviour anyway. What's the point?

Comment: your last pattern `xs -> "..."` **is** already a catch all - so is the question *why* you are not forced to use `_` or is it why the warning you get when you don't match all is not an error?

Comment: A better question to ask may be: *why can pattern matches in Haskell be non-exhaustive?* Because if one covers all cases explicitly, a catch-all would be superflous or even harmful.

Comment: If you want 100% safety use something like Coq. It will give you a compile error for cases like this since everything in Coq must be defined and all computations must halt. This comes at the price of making the language *non*-Turing complete and adding quite a lot of burden to the writer of a program to provide proofs for termination etc.

Comment: @n.m. It's a matter of taste, I guess. Personally, I would like having non-exhaustiveness being a compile-time error by default, unless explicitly deferred to runtime with a catch-all branch. If I had a `-Werror-on-incomplete-patterns` I would turn it on (`-Werror` is overkill for me).

Comment: @chi `-Werror is overkill for me` that's unfortunate :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Haskell is certainly *safer* than many other languages, especially mainstream ones, but it is far from 100% safe. Other unsafe features in Haskell include the ability to write infinite loops, like `let x = x in x`, or `unsafePerformIO`, or  `error`, or `undefined`.  I guess you could say it's just a tradeoff between convenience and safety.

In more complex code than your simple example, sometimes there's some cases that you know can't occur, and so you leave them out of your `case` expression, but Haskell's type system isn't strong enough for the compiler to be able know that those missing cases are impossible.  (For example you might be computing some mathematical function that can only return the numbers `3`, `4`, or `5`, but that fact is due to some difficult theorem that you happen to know about and which the compiler is not aware of.)

For what it's worth, you can pass `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns` to the `ghc` compiler to get a warning whenever at compile time you're missing a branch in a case statement, if you like.  That's included in the `-W` option which turns on several commonly desirable compiler warnings.

Comment: Another possible answer: GADTs make (sound and complete) exhaustiveness checking undecidable.

Comment: Also true! Though I think GADTs didn't exist when the decision was made not to do exhaustiveness checking on case statements in Haskell.

Comment: Don't forget that `-Werror` can effectively turn that warning into an error, just as the OP asked.

Answer (score 4):

A catch-all is not always needed. If one handles all cases explicitly (the pattern matching is *exhaustive*), a catch-all case would never be reached.

I can think of a serious drawback of a mandatory catch-all case: if one extends an ADT (algebraic data type), dependant code would still compile and the programmer is not reminded of that extra case they are supposed to handle.

Comment: yeah - but that's a comment and does not really answer the question

Comment: I disagree - this answer provides one possible explanation for why the catch-all case is not mandatory, by explaining one way in which the language would be harder to use correctly if it were mandatory. Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: This answers what the OP asked, but I wonder whether it answers what the OP intended to ask. I am unsure whether the actual question here is "why are non-exhaustive patterns allowed?".

Comment: Yeah @chi, I wrote a comment about that, too. The posed question is quite misleading.